# Wrong value of row obtained

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am using the `python.mysql` connector to access a MySQL table.

The MySQL database has a table `policy_data` which has a few columns, one being `application_no`.

The `application_no` column has values in the form of `t000...` totaling 8 digits including `t`.

Ideally, the first value of `application_no` column is `t0000001`.

So I pass a command (from Python):

```py
cursor.execute(select* application_no from policy_data where...(some condition)
data = cursor.fetchall()
appl = data[0][0] # this should give me 't0000001'
```

Here's the problem: I tried the above command as it is on MySQL, and it gives me `t0000001`. But from Python (the above code), the value (`appl=data[0][0]`) is coming as `t`.

I even tried putting the received value inside `str()`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is ''application_no" you first column in the table?

Comment: @IoaTzimas it is the second column...but I don't see how that should affect anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data=cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples (one tuple for each row of your table)

`appl=data[0][0]` returns the first element of the first tuple namely the value of first column of first row in your query result.

Given this, if column `'application_no'` is second in your query result (and it is as you use * in your query)  you will get the values of this column with data[i][1]

So if you check for `aapl=data[0][1]` it sould return your desired output `'t0000001'`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly your SQL query returns a list of strings. By doing

```
aapl=data[0][0]
```

you grab the first string, and then its first character 't'
maybe give

```
aapl=data[0]
```

a try